# Ghost letters and app display

Tags: samsung, android-10, samsung-galaxy-note-9, super-amoled

I was looking at some picture that had mainly white background and noticed that there is a certain ghost screen that was layered on top of it.
I edited a picture to try to bring out as much as possible.

From what I can actually see on the phone, it looks like the image of a whatsapp conversation as i can see the letters at the bottom of the screen as well as the typing bar with the camera on the side and the go back button in top left.

I tried to take screenshot but it doesn't show on the screenshot. Could it be the screen burning up?
In terms of actual color its between a brown / orange, copper like.

[image]

Comment: The Note 9 has an Super AMOLED display. Ghost images are typical for a worn out OLED display. https://www.cnet.com/how-to/oled-screen-burn-in-what-you-need-to-know-now/

Comment: @Robert is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The pixels that are darker are worn-out. This is a irreversible physical process. The only work-around that exists is to also worn-out the now brighter pixels so that all pixels have the same brightness level again. From OLED TVs I know that most of them has a program that tries to bring all pixels to the same level by illuminating pixels to worn-out them when the device is not used. For smartphones I don't know if such mechanisms exist or if the manufacturer assume that because of the short life-time this is negligible.